# What is the best way in RestKit to send off two requests then do a action only after both return?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a number of API calls I need to send off and then want to do something only when they all return, like `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];`

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you're making the requests, but `RKObjectManager` offers a number of options:

The `RKObjectManager` gives you access to the `operationQueue` on which the requests are running so you can check the `operationCount`.

The `RKObjectManager` also lets you `enqueueBatchOfObjectRequestOperations:...` with a progress and a completion callback.

Yet more, the `RKObjectManager` also lets you search for pending requests using `enqueuedObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:...`.

Comment: I've been using `getObjectsAtPath` which just has success and failure blocks. In order to get around my problem I've just been chaining requests through the success blocks but that seems like the dumb way to do it. So you're saying I can call getObjectsAtPath then watch the `operationQueue` for a 0 operationCount?

Comment: getObjectsAtPath will result in operations being created and added to the operationQueue so you can start both at the 'same' time and then check the operationCount in the completion block of each to decide which finishes second.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mutable NSArray and add some identifier to it when you send the request, and delete it when you get a response, and when the array is empty you are done.